# JavaScript onchange only works for select 3 and "all" but not in between

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

Not sure why this is happening but my JavaScript to change the number of past events shown isn't working properly. Only the first select option (3) and the last option (all) seem to fire the `onchange` event. Please look at my code and let me know if I am doing something wrong, I'm PHP person new at js. Also I will have it live on my demo site until I accept an answer: http://aaron-schpitzer.ca/en/events

**html(PHP)**

```
echo '<tr><td><table class="invisible"><tr><td>Number Shown: <select id="select" onchange="changePast()"><option value="3">3</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="'.count($pastEvents).'">All</option></select></td></tr></table></td></tr>';
```

**js**

```
<script>
var pastEvents = <?php echo json_encode($pastEvents); ?>;
function changePast(){
    var e = document.getElementById("select")
    var selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var table = document.getElementById("past_events");
    if(table!=null){
        var innerhtml = "";
        for(i=0;i<selected;i++){
            innerhtml+='<table class="invisible"><tr><td><img src="/'+pastEvents[i]["banner"]+'" alt="Event Banner"></td></tr><tr><td>'+pastEvents[i]["name"]+'</td></tr></table>';
        }
        table.innerHTML = innerhtml;
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think I have figured it out, there are only 5 past test events, so if I select a number I need to check if the value is greater than the # of objects and if so then I need to use the object.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, there are only 5 past test events, so if I select a number I need to check if the value is greater than the # of objects and if so then I need to use the object.length. Here is the added code before the for loop:

```
if(selected>pastEvents.length){
            selected = pastEvents.length;
}
```